# Is there GIS data for Electrical Cables under ground in US?

Tags: qgis, data

Where is GIS data for electrical cables under the ground in US ?
[AABSyS](http://www.aabsys.com/industries/utilities-gis/gis-for-electricity) seems to provide data, but I couldn't find out it after all.
The data might not be in public. In that case,
substitute to it, such as trans (under/above ground),
railway and so on, works for me.

Since I'm using QGIS, any data which can be imported into QGIS is preferable.

Comment: Any datasets related to underground infrastructure would be maintained by the relevant utilities, and possibly (but not always) by individual municipalities/counties. These datasets are almost always not publically available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see, I'll search for substitute to it !

Comment: A question requesting data is probably best placed at [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

Utilities don't generally like to make this sort of information publically available.  Even if it were compiled on a national level, they would be very sensitive to publication/disclosure.  If you are working directly with one of them on a relevant project, they might be willing to provide you their own data, but will most likely require an NDA.

Comment: @Daichi, if this post answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the green tick mark.